# Can IIS delay execution of code while appearing that it executed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a strange issue. A client added some data to our database through the website (ASP.NET MVC 4) at 7:30am. They e-mailed me right away to let me know the data wasn't appearing. I got the e-mail at 8:30am and checked if the data was there. It was. Our site logs showed it being added at 8:00am, a half hour after the user added it. The date in the log is actually calculated (just DateTime.Now call) in the server code, not in the database. That tells me that the server code ran at 8 and not 7:30 when it was initiated.

All the code is currently running synchronously, not async (I know, not great but haven't had time to fix it).

My question is whether there is any way that IIS could appear to execute a call but actually run it later?

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: Why suspect IIS? Probably a bug in your application. Is there anything that could take a long time? Any waiting? Any manual threading?

Comment: How is `7:30am` determined?  Can that value be trusted?  Could it be possible drifts due to timezone discrepancy of some sort?

Comment: @usr - I'm not completely convinced it's IIS but the MVC controller appears to return normally so that tells me it's not something else blocking. There's nothing waiting or any manual threading.

Comment: @LB2 - The 7:30 is determined by the date in the e-mail and confirmed by asking the user. Not perfect but the best I can do. Oh, I also entered some data myself and confirmed the date in database.

Comment: Are the clocks in sync everywhere? Or maybe the query that select the data is wrong so that it was invisible to the customer? This smells like a misinterpretation, not like an actual lag of 30min. Certainly, IIS cannot "suspend" writes that you have executed in your controller. IIS does not even know what a database is.

Comment: When client looked at the data, is it possible they got a cached version of a page that showed no data, whereas data was actually there?  Can you use IIS logs to check that after uploading data, the page to view the data was requested by the same client and that it returned full response (as opposed to Not Modified or akin to that)? Any proxies in between that may've serviced request preventing from user seeing the true and latest version of 'view data' page?

Comment: @usr - Because the date is created in code, not in the db, it seems like the actual code is being delayed, not the db write. As far as I know that's not possible but I wanted to verify.

Comment: @LB2 - I'm in the process of contacting the host now to get the logs, etc. There's no proxies or anything in the way that I know of.